# How to capture the screen of UWP web app

Tags: javascript, uwp

I want to take the screenshot of app running window in UWP javascript version.
As I got RenderTargetBitmap there for doing same but only available for C# version of UWP.

I want to do the same thing in UWP javascript app.

Please let me know could it possibly be done in UWP javascript app and HOW?

Any help would be highly appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: You might combine C# with JS, but I doubt you can do it with pure JS.

Comment: Yes, I am only dealing with pure javascript.
Is it possible to build C# with javascript and how to communicate with between them?
Please, would you share some links that support?

Comment: Please let me know it can't be done with javascript only?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-invoke-JS-at-Native-df3fd459

Comment: Thanks for sharing links.
But I want to do it with only JS.

Comment: With pure JS, I doubt you would be able to do it.

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/2889347

Comment: Yes, I used HTML2Canvas before but it does not capture video frame (screenshot). always black screen captured

Comment: Have you tried [html-screen-capture-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-screen-capture-js) package?

Answer (score 1):

We needed to get a screenshot of a web page using only javascript (no browser extensions, or user interaction). We've tried using html2canvas, but it seems like it can only handle a VERY basic UI. So, I wrote a small javascript library (html-screen-capture-js) for that purpose. Feel free to try it out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-screen-capture-js